# How could I create a desert sandstorm?

Tags: particles

So I am new to blender and I am trying to make a animation based in mars. In the end I want to have a huge sand storm to roll through the scene. However I can't find how to do this online so I'm asking here!Also My computers not the best so are there any ways to optimize it? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I guess the method depends on the level of realism you want, for realism you should probably try smoke (tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRqbTZYxRLY) by Iago Mota and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmRqlsuSvsw) by Polyfjord).

I've tried to fake it with the **Principled Volume** node in 2.8:

- You need to create a cube that you subdivide smooth. Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. It's your first cloud.
- Plug *Principled Volume* > *Volume* socket of the *Material Output*. Play with the *Principled Density* value to change its transparency.
- Plug *Noise* > *MixRGB* > *Color* socket of the *Principled* so that the surface of the cloud is a bit textured.
- Plug 2 *Musgrave* (or other textures) > *Math* (*Add* mode) > *Displacement* node > *Displacement* socket of the *Material Output* so that the cloud has 3D bumps.
- Put some additional nodes like *Texture Coordinate* > *Mapping* at the beginning of the nodes chain.

Duplicate this cloud. Increase its size, rotate 180° on the Z axis. Decrease the *Principled Volume Density* value of this second cloud to make it more transparent. This second cloud will encompass the first one.

To make them "roll" on the X axis, play with the X location value of the *Mapping* that comes before the *Musgrave* nodes.

Also, for more realism, on the forefront you could generate some particles, with a *Force Field* to make them move the way you want.

Blend file: [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the blend.

Comment: sure, done, please let me know if it can be improved